# Does this characterize the operator norm of the inverse?

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis

Let $A$ be an invertible operator (bounded with bounded inverse). Then
$$\frac{1}{\|A^{-1}\|} = \inf\left\{\frac{\|Av\|}{\|v\|} : v \neq 0\right\}$$

I believe I have a proof as follows, but I just want to double check

$$\begin{eqnarray*}
\inf\left\{\frac{\|Av\|}{\|v\|} : v \neq 0\right\} &=& \inf\left\{\frac{\|u\|}{\|A^{-1}u\|} : u \neq 0\right\} \\
&=& 1 / \sup\{\left\{\frac{\|A^{-1} u\|}{\|u\|} : u \neq 0\right\} \\
&=& \frac{1}{\|A^{-1}\|} 
\end{eqnarray*}$$
Is this correct?

Comment: Sounds good to me.

Comment: yes it is true. and we call $m(A)=\inf\left\{\frac{\|Av\|}{\|v\|} : v \neq 0\right\}$ the mininorm of $A$

Comment: @mac: Maybe that dpends on who "we" are.  I have never seen that terminology before.

Comment: @RobertIsrael: you can find this terminology in dynamical systems books and papers.